# ¿Por qué PHP no reconoce un archivo existente?

Tags: php

Al poner el siguiente código PHP:

```
if (!file("fun.inc.php")){
    include_once("../fun.inc.php");}
else
    include_once("fun.inc.php");
```

Sale este mensaje de error:

> Warning: file(fun.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Websites\Discernir2.0\web\articulos\articulos.php on line 4

Si el archivo existe, ¿Por qué no sigue adelante sin devolver el  mensaje de warning?

Gracias

Comment: Me imagino que fun.inc.php está en el mismo directorio que articulos.php ¿correcto?

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres comprobar, si el archivo existe, tienes que usar ***file_exists*** y no ***file*** que lo que te hace, es transferir el archivo a un ***array***  te dejo el ejemplo:

```
   if(file_exists("fun.inc.php")){
       include_once("../fun.inc.php");
   }else{
      include_once("fun.inc.php");
   }
```

> Nota: Asumo que la ruta de los archivos es correcta.

Comment: Esto ha resuelto el problema.

Comment: @SpearShaft,  Me alegro que le allá sido de utilidad

Comment: @SpearShaft márcala como aceptada, al costado de la respuesta hay un check, dale click :D